# PHP random_int seeding

Tags: php, random

As of PHP7, a new function was introduced for PRNG: random_int (http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php)

There is no information in the PHP manual related to the seeding of this function, nor I could find anything related to this online using Google.

Can I set the seed manually like it was possible with PHP srand or PHP mt_srand? Or I have no control over this? Or is the seeding done automatically and secure by the operating system?

Comment: They seem to be unseeded, from the `getrandom(2)` manpage: These bytes can be used to seed user-space random number generators or for cryptographic purposes. `getrandom()` relies on entropy gathered from device drivers and other sources of environmental noise.

Comment: It is not a RNG -- a true RNG is a deeply complex and processor heavy entity, this is a *Pseudo* RNG, (as stated on the manual page). Question updated.

Comment: You can still use `srand` and `mt_srand` with PHP7 which will allow you to use a seed -- http://php.net/manual/en/function.srand.php / http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-srand.php

Comment: @Martin actually this is a RNG, but in particular, it is a PRNG. Your statement that this is not a RNG is false. My statement that this is a RNG is correct.

Comment: Er, no, if you read the manual page you link to in your question it states: `Generates cryptographically secure pseudo-random integers`. Note the use of the word "Pseudo" in that sentence. `:-p`

Comment: rereading your comment, it seems your a bit confused about what a Random number and a Pseudo-random number is. Something that is a RNG can not also be a PRNG, It's like saying "I am a man" while also saying "I'm almost a man", they are mutually exclusive states. Pseudo-random numbers are **not** truly random. they can still be secure, but there is an important difference that the values they generate are not quite statistically random.

Comment: @Martin my point was that a RNG can be either a TRNG (true random number generator) or a PRNG (pseudo random number generator). If I say that something is a RNG, then it means that it does not matter what type of it is ... TRNG or PRNG . It's like saying "I am a human", instead of saying if I am a man or a woman.

Comment: but PRNG is *not* RNG. Anyhow, I think we're splitting infinitives, but I take the fact that PRNG have an extra letter to define them as not RNG is an important cryptological distinction.

Comment: Anywhooo Good luck with finding a seeding ability for it :)

Comment: @Martin well on linux you can seed it through RNDADDENTROPY , but you wont be the only seed, and i don't think it's going to do you any good, see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/random.4.html

Answer (score 2):

> Can I set the seed manually like it was possible with PHP srand or PHP mt_srand?

nope.

> Or I have no control over this?

correct (ish - on linux systems you can use the RNDADDENTROPY ioctl to seed the random generator from which practically everything on the entire system, including php, derives its cryptographically secure random bytes, but you probably don't want to do that, and it requires root)

> Or is the seeding done automatically and secure by the operating system?

correct, on Linux generated by the [getrandom() api](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrandom.2.html) (which is basically the same as reading from /dev/random and /dev/urandom ), and on Windows it's generated through the [BCryptGenRandom() api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/nf-bcrypt-bcryptgenrandom) using [BCRYPT_RNG_ALGORITHM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccng/cng-algorithm-identifiers#BCRYPT_RNG_ALGORITHM), and on OpenBSD & FreeBSD it uses [arc4random_buf() api](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=arc4random_buf&sektion=3&manpath=freebsd-release-ports) all 3 of which provides photographically secure random bytes, the relevant source code can be found at https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/bb6f374048bc0b4203e4fec7fd4e887519f663d6/ext/standard/random.c and https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/169805777c17892865ae462ae0a0895344a7fd3c/win32/winutil.c